# MySql access violation isn't in group with YEAR MONTH and MAX

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a data structure like this:

```
Table One
______________
| id  | name |
|------------|
| 1   | bob  |
| 2   | jane |
--------------

Table Two
_________________________________
| id  | table_1_id | date       |
|-------------------------------|
| 1   | 1          | 2000-01-01 |
| 2   | 1          | 2000-01-31 |
| 4   | 1          | 2000-02-28 |
| 5   | 1          | 2000-03-03 |
| 6   | 2          | 2000-01-03 |
| 7   | 2          | 2000-01-05 |
---------------------------------
```

I am attempting to only return the the highest (most recent) dates from table 2 that matches the user bob's id from table 1.

For instance, in the example above, I want to return this from my query

2000-01-31

2000-02-28

2000-03-03

What am trying now is

```
SELECT MAX(date)
FROM table_2
INNER JOIN table_1 ON table_1.id = table_2.table_1_id
WHERE table_1.name = "bob"
GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date)
ORDER BY date DESC
```

This seems to be working for me locally, but in production it fails because ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is enabled.

I don't want to disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY as I'd rather learn the proper way to build this query, but I can't seem to find out how to deal with YEAR/MONTH and MAX properly without getting the "isn't in GROUP BY" error.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ORDER BY` should be on either an aggregated expression or the expression defined in the `GROUP BY`.

So we need to sort by max date (value you are selecting) instead of date. In MySQL, we can define an alias and use the alias in `ORDER BY` clause

```
SELECT MAX(date) as max_date
FROM table_2
INNER JOIN table_1 ON table_1.id = table_2.table_1_id
WHERE table_1.name = 'bob'
GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date)
ORDER BY max_date DESC
```

Also don't use double quotes, but standard single quotes for string literals